# Error en NgFor Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

necesito algo de ayuda, estoy trabajando en un proyecto en angular sobre una agenda, pero cuando intento llamar a los objetos de base de datos me da el siguiente error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

mi servicio esta así:

```
getContact() {
    return this._http.get(this.url)
    .map(res => {
      this.contact = res.json();
    });
  }
```

y lo recibo aca:

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private contactService:ContactService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.contactService.getContact().subscribe();
    }
}
```

eso debería retornarme un json con los contactos en mi base de datos para luego mostrarlos en una tabla pero da el error antes dicho.

¿cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Nota que le estás pasando un objeto a `ngFor` mientras que está esperando una lista.

Answer (score 3):

Como bien dice ya el fallo que recibes, `ngFor` soporta solo una lista de array. Es decir tienes que meter tu resultado en un array.

Solución:

```
// Iniciar variable de la instancia
contact: Array<Object>;

getContact() {

    this._http.get(this.url)
        .map( res => res.json() )
        .subscribe( data => {

            this.contact = [];

            data.forEach( ( x ) => {

                this.contact.push( x );
            } );

        }, err => { } );
    }
```

y en el `ngOnInit` llamas la funcíón:

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.contactService.getContact();
}
```

Comment: Si data no es un array, no puedes hacer un forEach

Answer (score 0):

```
this._http.get(this.url)
    .map( res => res.json() )
    .subscribe( data => {

        this.data = data;

        var me = this;
        me.data = Object.keys(me.data ).map(function(key) {return me.data [key];});

}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta apareció en la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad. Esto sucede cuando se detecta que la publicación es sólo código o poco texto. Cuando publiques preguntas o respuestas, **debes incluir una explicación del código** *(no se trata solamente de publicar código)*.