# ¿Cómo iterar array de objetos o convertir el listado de objetos a un array?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, angular7, jsonobject

Tengo la siguiente estructura, cuando llamo la *API*:

```
{
  "recordsets": [
    [
      {
        "id_alquiler": 71735,
        "nombre_tipo_exhibidor": "Exhibidores de Temporada",
        "nombre_empresa": "TIOMAE",
        "nombre_estado_alquiler": "Por Montar",
        "marca": "ElTio",
        "nombre_sucursal": "EUAI"
      },
      {
        "id_alquiler": 71736,
        "nombre_tipo_exhibidor": "Exhibidores de Temporada",
        "nombre_empresa": "TIOELTOE",
        "nombre_estado_alquiler": "Por Montar",
        "marca": "Wuayba",
        "nombre_sucursal": "TOBAIE"
      },
```

Cuando llamo la *API* en mi componente ***.ts*** a través del explorador en inpeccionar me manda este error:

> Trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Tengo la interfaz con la estructura y tipado correo de los objetos bien tanto en el *back* como en el *front* en el mismo orden de cómo llamo los objetos, pero aún así me manda error, sé que es porque necesito convertir los objetos, pero he probado de varias formas con `.map()` y `.keys()` y no doy.

Esta es la función en el *backend* que retorna la consulta:

```
export async function listAlq(req: Request, res: Response) {
    console.time('loop')
    try {
        let response:Alquiler = await pool1.query(
            "Select query");   
        console.log(response);
        res.status(200).json(response);
    }
    catch(error) { //Capturando error
       console.error(error, 'Internal server Error', res.status(500));   
    }
    console.timeEnd('loop')
}
```

Componente ***.ts*** en Angular:

```
export class AlquileresComponent implements OnInit {

  alquiler: Alquiler[] = [];

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchAlq();
  }

  fetchAlq() {
    this.dataService.getAllAlq()
    .subscribe(alquiler => {
      this.alquiler = alquiler;
      console.log(alquiler);
    });
  }

}
```

Y la parte *HTML* del mismo componente:

```
<app-alquileres *ngFor="let alq of alquiler.recordsets">
    <div>
        <h5>{{ alq.id_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.marca }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_empresa }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_estado_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_sucursal }}</h5>
    </div>
</app-alquileres>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en NgFor Cannot find a differ supporting object '\[object Object\]'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86922/error-en-ngfor-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object)

Comment: @PabloLozano O sea, ya la vi, pero me recorre los objetos en el inspector de elemento de forma infinita, pero no logro pintar la data en pantalla.